# Browserify-shim - How to pass two global variables from one package into another

Tags: javascript, browserify, package.json, browserify-shim

I want to pass two variables(`$` and `jQuery`) from `jquery` package to `persian-datepicker`. So I added `$` and `jQuery` as a dependency of `persian-datepicker`. Is what I have done right?

But it seems that `browserify-shim` just can't export one variable from a single package.

Any Idea?

My `package.json`:

```js
...

"browser": {
    "jquery": "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    "persian-datepicker": "./node_modules/persian-datepicker/dist/js/persian-datepicker-0.4.5.js",
},
"browserify-shim": {
    "./node_modules/persian-datepicker/dist/js/persian-datepicker-0.4.5.js": {
        "depends": [
            "jquery:jQuery",
            "jquery:$"
        ]
    }
},
"browserify": {
    "transform": [
        "browserify-shim"
    ]
},

...
```

Answer (score 0):

What you've done works perfectly well - you can export both `$` and `jQuery` via browserify-shim without a problem.

If you're still trying to solve this what is the error you're getting?